# Error in Register.aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i created a new WebSite(csharp) in MV Web Developer 2010 and tried to register a new user via the Account/Register.aspx.
Somehow it wount work and spits out the following Error.

What am i doing wrong?

> Server Error in '/WebSite11'
>   Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation
>   error:
>
> The connection string specifies a
>   local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the
>   application's App_Data directory. The
>   provider attempted to automatically
>   create the application services
>   database because the provider
>   determined that the database does not
>   exist. The following configuration
>   requirements are necessary to
>   successfully check for existence of
>   the application services database and
>   automatically create the application
>   services database:
>
> If the application is running on
>   either Windows 7 or Windows Server
>   2008R2, special configuration steps
>   are necessary to enable automatic
>   creation of the provider database.
>   Additional information is available
>   at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102.
>   If the application's App_Data
>   directory does not already exist, the
>   web server account must have read and
>   write access to the application's
>   directory. This is necessary because
>   the web server account will
>   automatically create the App_Data
>   directory if it does not already
>   exist. If the application's App_Data
>   directory already exists, the web
>   server account only requires read and
>   write access to the application's
>   App_Data directory. This is necessary
>   because the web server account will
>   attempt to verify that the Sql Server
>   Express database already exists within
>   the application's App_Data directory.
>   Revoking read access on the App_Data
>   directory from the web server account
>   will prevent the provider from
>   correctly determining if the Sql
>   Server Express database already
>   exists. This will cause an error when
>   the provider attempts to create a
>   duplicate of an already existing
>   database. Write access is required
>   because the web server account's
>   credentials are used when creating the
>   new database. Sql Server Express must
>   be installed on the machine. The
>   process identity for the web server
>   account must have a local user
>   profile. See the readme document for
>   details on how to create a local user
>   profile for both machine and domain
>   accounts.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A
>   network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   +5009598    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   +234    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds
>   connHandler, Boolean
>   ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean
>   trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity) +341
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection
>   owningObject) +129
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout,
>   SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +195
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +232
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +5023255
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +31
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +76
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   +125    System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String
>   server, String user, String password,
>   Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString) +82
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to
>   connect to SQL Server database.]
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String
>   server, String user, String password,
>   Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString) +137
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String
>   server, String user, String password,
>   Boolean trusted, String
>   connectionString, String database,
>   String dbFileName, SqlFeatures
>   features, Boolean install) +94
>   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String
>   database, String dbFileName, String
>   connectionString) +27
>   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String
>   fullFileName, String dataDir, String
>   connectionString) +395
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: Check your DB connection string?

Comment: Seems the error message is pretty clear. Did you try going through the steps it lists, or are you saying that you know the error you're getting is caused by something else?

Comment: Funny, I don't think the error message could contain anything more about what the error is and what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Did you read http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102 yet?

Answer (score 1):

Check you connection string in the web.config, it is incorrect or you have not set up sqlexpress on your server correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify your connection string to the SQL database being used is correct?  If you didn't know you had an MS-SQL database back-end then that may be a good starting point in trying to see what went wrong looking at that error message.

---

Did you check that your MS-SQL server being used allows remote connections?  I've seen that probably pop up at times where there were settings to change.  Also beware of what form of authentication are you using to access MS-SQL as there is Windows authentication and an explicit MS-SQL username/password combinations that could also be used.